# How to analyze low-level OSGi problems during tycho test execution?

Tags: tycho

When executing JUnit test with [tycho-surefire-plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-surefire/tycho-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html), tycho forks an equinox runtime.
In rare cases it may happen that some bundles in the OSGi test runtime cannot be resolved/started (e.g. package uses conflicts).
If you read the debug log (maven CLI option `-X`), you will find something like

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-08 16:41:31.635
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-08 16:41:31.635
An error has occurred. See the log file
C:\mytestproject.tests\target\work\configuration\1349705136008.log.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12:03.181s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 08 16:17:16 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:0.15.0:test (default-test) on project mytestproject.tests: An unexpected error occured (return c
ode 13). See log for details. -> [Help 1]
```

The eclipse console log does not provide enough information in case of package uses conflicts.

How can I analyze the bundles in the OSGi test runtime forked by tycho?

Answer (score 8):

start tests in remote debug mode (simply specify `-DdebugPort=8000` on the CLI) and start the OSGi console on a local port, e.g. 1234:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                  <osgi.console>1234</osgi.console>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Set a breakpoint in one of your test classes or in org/eclipse/tycho/surefire/osgibooter/OsgiSurefireBooter if tests are not even started. Then,

```
 telnet localhost 1234
```

and you can use the usual OSGi console commands like `ss, diag, bundle` etc. to analyze the problem "in vivo".

Comment: I had to add one additional systemProperty: <osgi.console.enable.builtin>true</osgi.console.enable.builtin>. With that it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can run with `-consolelog` or set the `eclipse.consoleLog` property to `true` property.  If you're running with Tycho, you can use `<argLine>-Declipse.consoleLog=true</argLine>`.