# OSGi console after running tycho tests

Tags: eclipse, osgi, tycho

I wonder is there any way to tell the osgi console in eclipse not to exit after running tests with tycho-surefire-plugin?

I have tried out `<argLine>-Dosgi.noShutdown=true</argLine>` and `<appArgLine>-console -noExit</appArgLine>`, but I do not get what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to analyze low-level OSGi problems during tycho test execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784087/how-to-analyze-low-level-osgi-problems-during-tycho-test-execution)

Comment: I finally succeeded in getting to the OSGi console by starting the tycho test in the remote debug mode. However in contrast to the above mentioned solution I had to  use the following configuration:
<argLine>-ea -Dosgi.clean=true -Ddebug=true -Dosgi.console.enable.builtin=true</argLine>
<appArgLine>-console 1234 -noExit</appArgLine>

Comment: Right on. Feel free to submit it as an answer, and accept it - that way it will stay out of the unanswered questions queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally succeeded in getting to the OSGi console by starting the tycho test in the remote debug mode. However in contrast to the above mentioned solution I had to use the following configuration:

```
<argLine>-ea -Dosgi.clean=true -Ddebug=true -Dosgi.console.enable.builtin=true</argLine>  
<appArgLine>-console 1234 -noExit</appArgLine>
```

Comment: This approach did not work for me. I needed a breakpoint in Tycho Surefire plugin and the configuration mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12784090/337621